# Oracle 12c - DBA_USERS table - does LAST_LOGIN mean last successful login, or last attempted login?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Oracle 12c.

I'm not a DBA so maybe this is a dumb question or clarified within the context of DB convention.

When I review the DBA_USERS table, does the column 'LAST_LOGIN' refer to the last successful login (i.e. someone is still successfully using that account) or the last *attempted* login (i.e. someone might be trying to log in with the wrong creds)

Hope that's not too simple a question for format. Bafflingly googling turned up nothing, and the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-309FCCB2-2E8D-4371-9FC5-7F3B10E2A8C0.htm#REFRN23302) are not helpful

> LAST_LOGIN | The time of the last user login.

Maybe it's just me...

Thanks You!

Comment: Why don't you simply try it out?

Comment: @Erich - fair questions. I was trying to look into an issue with accounts on that schema: So I didn’t wanna muddy the water by taking actions with the account myself. I suppose I could’ve asked the DBA to setup a separate test account, but after checking the docs, and finding nothing on google, I figured it was worth just asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the time of the last **successful** login.

You can find out yourself: open a SQL*Plus session and try to log in, but give an incorrect password. Then run `select last_login from dba_users where username = 'YOURNAME';` - you will see that the time of your failed login is not recorded in the table.